# Abelian group of subspaces with a metric

Tags: co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory

Hello all,

I am new here.I apologize for wrong tags, or any other mistake on my part.

Let ${\cal P}(\mathbb{F}_2^n)$ stand for the set of all subspaces of $\mathbb{F}_2^n$.

Define a metric $d_S$ on ${\cal P}(\mathbb{F}_2^n)$ as $d_S(A,B) = \text{dim}(A+B) - \text{dim}(A \cap B)$.

Let $({\cal G}, *)$ be an Abelian group where ${\cal G} \subseteq {\cal P}(\mathbb{F}_2^n)$ and $d_S(A*B, 0) = d_S(A,B)$ where $0$ is the identity of $({\cal G}, *)$.

There is a conjecture that largest size of such a ${\cal G}$ is $2^n$. [The largest size is guessed to be $2^n$, since one can construct such a $\cal G$ by picking the span of arbitrary subsets of a chosen basis of $ \mathbb{F}_2^n $ ]

I do not know how to proceed to attack this conjecture. I have tried various ways and most of them involve picking a basis. I wonder if I need more abstraction on this. Has there been attempts to force a group structure on set of subspaces with a nice geometry before?

P.S:
It is easy to see a few things, that:

1) if dim$(A \cap B) = 0$, then $A*B = A \oplus B$

2) if $X_1 = X_2 * X_3$, then dim$(X_i)$ = dim$(X_i \cap X_j)$ + dim$(X_i \cap X_k )$ for $i \neq j$ and $j\neq k$ and $k \neq i$ and $i,j,k \in \{1,2,3\}$.

Thank you,

Comment: Do you have a reference for the conjecture? Thanks for posting this, it seems very interesting!

Comment: I had independently derived the results of the paper given below. I have partial leads on the conjecture but the general link seems to be missing.

Here is the reference:
http://arxiv.org/abs/1103.3117