# The largest size of a boolean subgraph (a hypercube) of a given graph

Tags: co.combinatorics, linear-algebra, graph-theory

Let $G(\mathbb{F}_2^n)$ denote the graph that represents the lattice of all subspaces of $\mathbb{F}_2^n$ (also called a [Hasse diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasse_diagram)). I am interested in knowing if there exists a large [hypercube](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercube_graph) subgraph in $G(\mathbb{F}_2^n)$.

Let the largest $m$ for which $Q_m$ is embeddable into $G(\mathbb{F}_2^n)$ be denoted by $M$. We can claim $M \geq 2^n$, since we can span all the various subsets of the standard basis, which will give us a $Q_{2^n}$ subgraph of $G$.

So my question is: Can we claim that $M$ is at most $2^n$?

[Note: It is related to my earlier question, a few years ago: [Abelian group of subspaces with a metric](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/76481/abelian-group-of-subspaces-with-a-metric) ]

Comment: Considered as posets yes. As a vertex induced subgraph, maybe yes, but I am unsure.  As an edge induced subgraph, probably not, as you have the chance of "folding" the graph over and squeezing it into the subspace graph, but I don't have explicit numbers for you.

Comment: Also, it matters whether you have the graph of covering relations or its transitive closure.  In the above I am guessing wrt to covering relations.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. My main intention is the lattice. So about "Considered as posets yes." Why would that be true?

Comment: Here is my hand-waving belief, which you can probably formalize.  I will borrow your M.  Consider two opposed elements of Q_M.  They are end points of chains of length n edges.  The chains in the subspace lattice have length at most n, so M can't be any bigger.  If I have misread or misunderstood something that breaks the above, I apologize.  Hopefully the hand waving is still useful.

Comment: Voting to close as already answered in the comments.